# Apache server – trying to use Location directive in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I need to remove all caching when a specific path (/foo/bar/) is called on my website.
My managed hosting support tells me that I should do this in .htaccess and I have tried to use the Location directive, like so:

```
<Location "/foo/bar/">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
</Location>
```

But all I get is an internal server error. Did I leave something out or should this directive be placed in a certain place in .htaccess. I have tried everything I can think of, with the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has already been mentioned, the `<Location>` directive is not permitted in `.htaccess` files. If `/foo/bar/` relates directly to a filesystem directory then you can place the `.htaccess` file in that directory to apply the directives (`Header` in this case) to that directory and below only.

However, if `/foo/bar/` is a URL-path only (which is also what the `<Location>` directive targets in a server context), which does not relate directly to the filesystem, then you can instead set an environment variable when that URl-path is accessed and set the `Header` conditionally based on whether that env var is set.

For example:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/foo/bar/$" NO_CACHE
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" env=NO_CACHE
```

The above sets the env var `NO_CACHE` (to the value `1`) when the URL-path `/foo/bar/` (only) is requested and the `Header` directive is then only applied when that env var is set (by the last argument `env=NO_CACHE`).

---

Alternatively, if you are on Apache 2.4+ then you can use [Apache `<If>` expressions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) to directly target that URL-path only, negating the need to set an env var. For example:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/foo/bar/$#">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
</If>
```

---

Another alternative, if you are on Apache 2.4.10+ then you can use an [Apache expression](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) directly in the `Header` directive in order to target that URL-path only. For example:

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" "expr=%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/foo/bar/$#"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer. This works as I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location), the `Location` directive cannot be used in `.htaccess` file at all. You can use `Location` in the server config, but the `.htaccess` file always refers to the current directory in which the file resides, so specifying directives for another location in that file is pointless.

Simply leave the `Location` directive out, the `Header` itself should work for that directory / location.

Comment: Ahh, that explains it. I can now see it's the same thing with the Directory directive. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I've edited the answer. I forgot to mention a solution (simply leave the `Location` out). Oops.

Comment: Thanks Lacek, I will try that.